# Perforability - a correct term similar to Russian "перфорированность", meaning "relative area of a surface occupied by pores"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, translation, russian

I'm looking for the correct translation of the Russian term "перфорированность" and find the "perforability" but don't know, is it correct?

From the physical point of view "perforability" means *the relative area of a surface occupied by pores*.

This term can be used in (scientific) papers.

For example, the sentense

> To calculate *the relative area of perforations (pores) on the surface* of crystal slices, we use the following method ...

can be changed to a new one

> To calculate *the perforability* of crystal slices, we use the following method ...

There is a close term "porosity" that means *the relative volume of a solid occupied by pores*. But I need a term for the surface area.

Can perforability be used for this?

Comment: The question may be closed because it is about Russian translation, But if you give an example sentence of the use of the word, we may be able to help you.

Comment: Added an example. Is it enough?

Comment: Probably density is a useful term here.

Comment: Pores density? May be, but I'd like to underline perforations.

Comment: If _perforability_ is a word, which I doubt, it would mean _the ability to be perforated_, not _the area that is perforated_.

Comment: Google translate gives перфорированность as "perforation". In English, that usually refers to a single hole. To distinguish it from a single hole, you might say "degree of perforation".

Comment: What is better: "degree of perforation(s)" or "density of perforations"? And do we need an "s" in the first example?

Comment: @IvanZ In that use, *perforation* is a process, so singular. In your first example, you might say *...area occupied by perforations...*, with plural. Another possibility would be to look for a Russian scientific paper using *перфорированность*, and find out how it has been translated in the past.

Comment: [There is only one Russian paper](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=ru&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=intitle%3Aперфорированность) that includes "перфорированность" in title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OP requests a term for "the relative area of a surface occupied by pores."

**porosity / surface porosity**

The definition of *porosity* is

> The ratio of the volume of interstices of a material to the volume of
> its mass [m-w](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/porosity)

**Porosity** characterizes the **volumetric** aspect of the pore system. [Jürgen Schön; *Physical Properties of Rocks*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Physical_Properties_of_Rocks/ZkFpYNNgGLUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22surface%20porosity%22&pg=PA29&printsec=frontcover)

However, *porosity* appears to be used for surfaces as well.

> A modified theory of the later, ..., applies to non-porous
> surfaces. Standard curves are more useful, especially if one is
> interested in **porosity**, although most depend upon calibration by
> some other interpretation, usually the BET. (p.56)
>
> ***Surface** Area and **Porosity** Determinations by Physiorption* [graph caption]
> (p.130)
>
> [James B. Condon; ***Surface** Area and **Porosity** Determinations by
> Physisorption: Measurements and Theory*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Surface_Area_and_Porosity_Determinations/5046xYN8wcIC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=porosity%20of%20a%20surface&printsec=frontcover) (2006)

> ONC® is a process that takes advantage of **surface porosity**
> observed in most compound layers after nitriding. It is a simple
> concept but the process is not easy in that the amount of **porosity**
> generated during the nitriding stage must be properly controlled.
> [ASM, and N. Dahotre; *Heat Treating and Surface Engineering*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Heat_Treating_and_Surface_Engineering/io9laaRnoswC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22surface%20porosity%22&pg=PA250&printsec=frontcover)
> (2003)

> The original Cassie equation did not include a term for **porosity**, but
> it was expanded to include **surface porosity**... [Felix N. Büchi et
> al.; *Polymer Electrolyte Fuel Cell Durability*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Polymer_Electrolyte_Fuel_Cell_Durability/7OMcQ6y4Z8cC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22surface%20porosity%22&pg=PA176&printsec=frontcover)  (2009)

> In general, the higher the porosity, the higher the permeation flux.
> Depending on the fabricate technique, its pore distribution can be
> inhomogeneous, resulting in a **surface porosity** that differs from
> the **bulk porosity**. [J. Hu et al.; *Handbook of Fibrous Materials,
> Vol. 1*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Handbook_of_Fibrous_Materials_2_Volumes/NyvfDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=In%20general,%20the%20higher%20the%20porosity,%20the%20higher%20the%20permeation%20flux.%20Depending%20on%20the%20fabricate%20technique,%20its%20pore%20distribution%20can%20be%20inhomogeneous,%20resulting%20in%20a%20surface%20porosity%20that%20differs%20from%20the%20bulk%20porosity.&pg=PT1013&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: I choose this answer as best, but I also like the @PhilSweet answer. Unfortunately it is impossible to choose two answers as best.

Comment: And what do you imagine, when listen artificial word "perforosity"?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, seeing *perforosity*, I would think that it's a mistake and the writer didn't know *porosity*, or that the writer means something different. :-) *Perforosity* calls to mind the verb *perforate*: to make holes, so perhaps "the ease or difficulty of making holes/be punctured"??

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is a 2D or pseudo 2D situation, where the areas in question are projections on a plane. That's pretty much the only way that a pore has an area that is different from the solid surface area.

Relative measurements are rendered as coefficients in technical English, or sometimes as *specific X*. There doesn't appear to be an established single term for this. And there are several seemingly appropriate terms that are already claimed for different measurements and that have test standards and definitions.

After surveying some technical documents on filters, I suggest "relative pore surface coverage" as used in the abstract which follows - https://cyberleninka.org/article/n/1416663

Comment: Also a term "relative pore covered area" is used. Thank you.

Comment: I like this answer and will be use proposed phrase as an alternative for "porosity", but I select the porosity as the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the context and your helpful example, I suggest that *permeability*, which is a term commonly understood in physics, engineering and geology, might satisfy your need.

> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permeability)
>
> permeability:
>
> the quality or state of being permeable
>
> [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/permeability)
>
> permeable:
>
> capable of being permeated : Penetrable
> especially : having pores or openings that permit liquids or gases to pass through
>
> // permeable membrane"

The concept applies to three-dimensional structures but, as the Merriam Webster example of *membrane* suggests, it also applies to a thin structure or surface such as your thin crystal slices.

Comment: [Britannica says](https://www.britannica.com/science/permeability-physics) that "The standard unit of permeability is the darcy, equivalent to the passage of one cubic centimetre of fluid (having a viscosity of one centipoise) per second through a sample one square centimetre in cross-sectional area under a pressure of one atmosphere per centimetre of thickness". So, the permiability is not a measure of a surface of perforations. To measure permiability it is necessary to take into account too many parameters.

Comment: Moreover "permeability" has a Russian equivalent "проницаемость" that is not equal to "перфорированность".

Comment: @IvanZ Permeability is the concept. The Britannica quote refers to how to measure the concept. As regards the second comment about cross-translation, there are many words that do not translate exactly or uniquely from one language to another and back, and to argue that they do easily leads to error. But this site is not about translation, it is about English usage.

Comment: OK, lets consider my term "perforability". As a native English speaker, what do you imagine when you listen word "perforability"? Is it syntactically correct term?

Comment: @IvanZ - The problem I have with perforability is that it sounds like a measure of how easily something can be perforated.

Comment: @IvanZ As a native speaker and as a physicist and earth scientist who has long experience of the solid state, I have never heard the term perforability used for anything. On the other hand, permeability as applied to three and two dimensional lattices is well known,

Comment: Whoever downvoted permeability is doggedly pursuing their own notions in opposition to dictionary usage.

Comment: @Anton, which SI units are used for measuring permeability of 2D lattice? And does surface area of pores is enought to estimate permiability?

Comment: @IvanZ We try on this site to answer questions about English Usage and not to go beyond what is necessary to do that. This question is about word choice, meaning and usage. .It is not about measurement or units of measurement of anything. If you wish to discuss those I suggest going to the Stack Exchange Physics site.